# how to call a js function defined in a codeigniter view from codeigniter controller method?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3

This is my contoller function n i want to call developer() function defined in a view called chat_developer.

```
function developer_via_superadmin() {
    echo '<script>'
    . 'developer();'
    . '</script>';
  }
```

Here is the devleloper function defined in the view

```
script>
     function developer() {
       alert("Developer function called from controller");    
    }
   </script>
```

But when i call it from controller. Console gives an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: developer is not defined
```

Comment: Because of poor[/ly explained] design/idea/concept seems like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying: calling one JS function from another JS function? My question is *why* - there is no much code presented.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the JS function some where above the place where you call it.
i.e as the error says, the function must be defined before it could be called.